# Oauth Freelancer.com Failed to find token

Tags: php, oauth, drupal-7, freelancer.com-api

I'm currenty using drupal, with the [oauthconnector](http://drupal.org/project/oauthconnector), to interact with different services.

I'm trying to connect with Freelancer.com (Sandbox environment), and I'm getting an error when I have logged in to the service (REMOVED_984c3db">https://www.sandbox.freelancer.com/users/api-token/auth.php?oauth_token=21b7e73_*REMOVED*_984c3db - I have removed some of the oauth_token here, just for safety :) )

> Failed to find token.
>
> In 1 seconds you'll be redirected automatically.
>
> Or click here to continue.

Comment: Can you post some code how are you trying do it?

Comment: Actually, I'm just using the library.
I can intercept all the oauth traffic, if it has interest?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured this out.

The normal behaviour in the OAUTH protocol, for getting the requestToken, is to send a HTTP-POST, containing a http.authorization header. The data in this, is the following

oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_nonce=\"87_*HIDDEN*_66bd\",oauth_timestamp=\"1365000670\",oauth_consumer_key=\"de99_*HIDDEN*_cf18\",oauth_callback=\"htt_*HIDDEN*_Fauthorized\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_signature=\"hyT_*HIDDEN*_sc%3D\"

Sadly, freelancer.com can't accept this. These parameter MUST be send in a HTTP-GET, with the data as query-parameters.

Like so: /RequestRequestToken/requestRequestToken.json?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=5bb_*HIDDEN*_144&oauth_timestamp=1365013875&oauth_consumer_key=de9_*HIDDEN*_cf18&oauth_callback=http_*HIDDEN*_authorized&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=qkX_*HIDDEN*_3D

A wierd thing is though, that the "wrong" request actually returns a request_token - that just doesn't work.